# Using Typescript to Return Greatest Number from key in Array

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, mapreduce, reduce

Let's say I have an array such as:

```
gamers = [
   {
     player: 'john',
     points: 20,
   },
   {
     player: 'jim',
     points: 10,
   },
   {
     player: 'greg',
     points: 11,
   },
   {
     player: 'jane',
     points: 21,
   },
]
```

I want to iterate through the array of objects and find the best combination of 2 players that will result in the highest combination of points. How can I do this using Typescript?

Comment: What have you already tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the `gamers` array based on descending order of points, and the first two elements will have the two highest scores, the combination of which will give you the highest points.

```
gamers.sort((a, b): number => {
    return b.points - a.points;
}).slice(0, 2);
```